# How can I make an JSON in Java with org.json which does look like this example?

Tags: java, json

So, I tried something with java which looks like this, but the output does not look nice.

One of the code-examples I tried to make a json file with:

```
        String name = "usericals.json";
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

        JSONArray scene = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray element = new JSONArray();


        jsonObj.put("scene", scene);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 1; ii++) {
                element.put(write);
            }
            jsonObj.put("element", element);

        }
        scene.put(element);

        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("new.json", "UTF-8")) {
            writer.write(jsonObj.toString(4));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("exception " + ex);
        }
```

I wanted to make a json file which looks like this but I cannot get it right. I am creating with my code above only arrays. Does anyone have an idea or suggestion?

The JSON File I want:

```
{
  "scene": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "calendar_event": "urlaub",
      "element": [
        {
          "anything": ""
        },
        {
          "anything": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "calendar_event": "urlauburlaub",
      "element": [
        {
          "anything": ""
        },
        {
          "anything": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "calendar_event": "urlauburlauburlaub",
      "element": [
        {
          "anything": ""
        },
        {
          "device": "",
          "anything": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "calendar_event": "urlauburlauburlauburlaub",
      "element": [
        {
          "anything": ""
        },
        {
          "anything": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes you definitely can, the example JSON is valid. Could you post the JSON your code is outputting to save readers some time trying to figure that out? Also as StaxMan said, I would recommend you use a library like Jackson for something like this, it will save you a lot of headache with all these loops.

Comment: It might be good to briefly also mention why you want to use `org.json` library: there are many Java JSON libraries that are often more convenient to use, so one option might be (or maybe not, depending on your situation) to use another library like GSON or Jackson instead.

Comment: i updated my question with the output but the output is rather ... far away from the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSONObject recursively. Try something like this (I add some extra indentation so it can be readed easily, but on real projects better use functions instead):

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
  JSONArray scene = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject node = new JSONObject();
    node.put("id", 0);
    node.put("calendar_event", "urlaub");
      JSONArray element = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject enode = new JSONObject();
        enode.put("anything", "");
      element.add(enode);
      //...
    node.put("element", element);
  scene.add(node);
json.put("scene", scene);
//...
```

Note like this you generate manually the JSONs, but there are other libraries that scan objects to generate jsons. Depending on your needs, it could be easer, but remember that making so you are going to overhead everything because you are going to need to hold in memory two copies of the same tree. Also dealing with hierarchical structures maybe a problem using plain java objects.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using library for that. Jackson or GSON would be a good choice.

Instead of manually creating json field by field you could create POJOs and then use Jackson's ObjectMapper. Example:

```
public class Car {

    private String color;
    private String type;

    // standard getters setters
}
```

and then

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Car car = new Car("yellow", "renault");
objectMapper.writeValue(new File("target/car.json"), car);
```

Which will give

```
{"color":"yellow","type":"renault"}
```

Google has a lot of jackson tutorials!

Comment: Do you maybe know how this would work with the Library org.json ? Best regards

Comment: In Jackson you can use modules. There is module for supporting org.json -> https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-json-org

Comment: But in general you should use Jackson instead of org.json, not with it